# New Orchid growing from main Plant

Tags: propagation

I have had this trusty orchid for many years and it has given me many lovely sprays of flowers but now it has given me a baby orchid! I have propagated from stem plants but not sure how to deal with this.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything IanJ. At least, not now. Perhaps when the new orchid starts to get a bit bigger you might think about re-potting or perhaps you might think about separating the two orchids all together. Congratulations, it's a girl.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you have a basal baby. You should wait a little while for the baby to grow roots 1.5-2 inches and separate the baby from the mother. Next, you need to put the baby in a separate pot and take care of her like all adult orchids. [You can learn more about how to grow an orchid from a baby here](https://perspor.ru/orhidei-2/razvedenie-orhidej/kak-vyrastit-orhideyu-iz-detki-v-domashnih-usloviyah/)

Comment: The link is to a site in Russian and of limited use to English speakers

Comment: HI, please post the essentials from the link here.  Readers should not need to click on links to see the answer.  Links are perfectly valid or attribution or for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

to propagate orchids you have 2 options

1st method is the Stem Cutting method which you mentioned in the question.

2nd method is the Keiki Cutting method.
(the best way in my opinion)

[image]

keep the keiki with its mother for now until  gets at least 2-3 leaves 
and at least 1 inch long roots

caution only separate the plants when your keiki is ready 
there is no need to rush 
as @rob suggested

1 ) water the mother plant the day before you choose to separate the two to give the keiki a better chance of survival.

2) then cut  the baby orchid below the roots so that it can sustain itself  with it's own roots.

3) pot your new orchid in a suitable  growing medium just like the mother has.

:) free orchid

keiki = baby in Hawaiian

Comment: I always thought a Keiki was defined as a new plant growing _on the flower stalk_ (for Phalaenopsis), not what we are seeing here?

Comment: it's a baby keiki the best type :)